# implement SIP protocol in arm-cortex-m4 FREERTOS

Tags: arm, sip, pjsip, freertos, cortex-m

I have been working VOIP software for some time now. I have a 88MW300 (ARM CORTEX M4) micro controller and i was wondering if i could implement SIP Protocol in the controller So that I may be able to use that device as a IP Phone to make and receive calls.
This Controller uses FreeRTOS OS and thus if there is any way to build SIP stacks would also be helpful.
I am very much new to Micro controllers and building firmware into it.So any kind of help will be appreciated.

I Tried using PJSIP source Code to compile in the board. But it is not fully compatible and gives quite a few errors. Reason being PJSIP does not have config for freertos. and also PJSIP is very large compared to the flash memory of the board. I am focusing on reducing the size later but want to successfully built it first.

The basic config file for any os is something like this.

```
#ifndef __PJ_COMPAT_OS_LINUX_H__
#define __PJ_COMPAT_OS_LINUX_H__

/**
 * @file os_linux.h
 * @brief Describes Linux operating system specifics.
 */

#define PJ_OS_NAME          "linux"

#define PJ_HAS_ARPA_INET_H      1
#define PJ_HAS_ASSERT_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_CTYPE_H          1
#define PJ_HAS_ERRNO_H          1
#define PJ_HAS_LINUX_SOCKET_H       0
#define PJ_HAS_MALLOC_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_NETDB_H          1
#define PJ_HAS_NETINET_IN_H     1
#define PJ_HAS_SETJMP_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_STDARG_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_STDDEF_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_STDIO_H          1
#define PJ_HAS_STDLIB_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_STRING_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_IOCTL_H      1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_SELECT_H     1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_SOCKET_H     1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_TIME_H       1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_TIMEB_H      1
#define PJ_HAS_SYS_TYPES_H      1
#define PJ_HAS_TIME_H           1
#define PJ_HAS_UNISTD_H         1
#define PJ_HAS_SEMAPHORE_H      1

#define PJ_HAS_MSWSOCK_H        0
#define PJ_HAS_WINSOCK_H        0
#define PJ_HAS_WINSOCK2_H       0

#define PJ_HAS_LOCALTIME_R      1

#define PJ_SOCK_HAS_INET_ATON       1

/* Set 1 if native sockaddr_in has sin_len member. 
 * Default: 0
 */
#define PJ_SOCKADDR_HAS_LEN     0

/**
 * If this macro is set, it tells select I/O Queue that select() needs to
 * be given correct value of nfds (i.e. largest fd + 1). This requires
 * select ioqueue to re-scan the descriptors on each registration and
 * unregistration.
 * If this macro is not set, then ioqueue will always give FD_SETSIZE for
 * nfds argument when calling select().
 *
 * Default: 0
 */
#define PJ_SELECT_NEEDS_NFDS        0

/* Is errno a good way to retrieve OS errors?
 */
#define PJ_HAS_ERRNO_VAR        1

/* When this macro is set, getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR) will return
 * the status of non-blocking connect() operation.
 */
#define PJ_HAS_SO_ERROR             1

/* This value specifies the value set in errno by the OS when a non-blocking
 * socket recv() can not return immediate daata.
 */
#define PJ_BLOCKING_ERROR_VAL       EAGAIN

/* This value specifies the value set in errno by the OS when a non-blocking
 * socket connect() can not get connected immediately.
 */
#define PJ_BLOCKING_CONNECT_ERROR_VAL   EINPROGRESS

/* Default threading is enabled, unless it's overridden. */
#ifndef PJ_HAS_THREADS
#  define PJ_HAS_THREADS        (1)
#endif

#define PJ_HAS_HIGH_RES_TIMER       1
#define PJ_HAS_MALLOC               1
#ifndef PJ_OS_HAS_CHECK_STACK
#   define PJ_OS_HAS_CHECK_STACK    0
#endif
#define PJ_NATIVE_STRING_IS_UNICODE 0

#define PJ_ATOMIC_VALUE_TYPE        long

/* If 1, use Read/Write mutex emulation for platforms that don't support it */
#define PJ_EMULATE_RWMUTEX      0

/* If 1, pj_thread_create() should enforce the stack size when creating 
 * threads.
 * Default: 0 (let OS decide the thread's stack size).
 */
#define PJ_THREAD_SET_STACK_SIZE        0

/* If 1, pj_thread_create() should allocate stack from the pool supplied.
 * Default: 0 (let OS allocate memory for thread's stack).
 */
#define PJ_THREAD_ALLOCATE_STACK        0

/* Linux has socklen_t */
#define PJ_HAS_SOCKLEN_T        1


#endif  /* __PJ_COMPAT_OS_LINUX_H__ */
```

Again i am a little blurry as to what parameters should i put for FREERTOS.

Another error i get is in error generation.
the Error generation file (errorno.h) is given as.

```
#ifndef __PJ_COMPAT_ERRNO_H__
#define __PJ_COMPAT_ERRNO_H__

#if defined(PJ_WIN32) && PJ_WIN32 != 0 || \
    defined(PJ_WIN32_WINCE) && PJ_WIN32_WINCE != 0 || \
    defined(PJ_WIN64) && PJ_WIN64 != 0

    typedef unsigned long pj_os_err_type;
#   define pj_get_native_os_error()     GetLastError()
#   define pj_get_native_netos_error()      WSAGetLastError()

#elif defined(PJ_HAS_ERRNO_VAR) && PJ_HAS_ERRNO_VAR!= 0

    typedef int pj_os_err_type;
#   define pj_get_native_os_error()     (errno)
#   define pj_get_native_netos_error()      (errno)

#else

#   error "Please define how to get errno for this platform here!"

#endif


#endif  /* __PJ_COMPAT_ERRNO_H__ */
```

I have no idea what parameters do i add for my platform.

These are the few errors i get while compiling, After that i think i will succesfully build it.
Any kind of help will be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Have you read the [FAQ](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#platforms) and the [porting instructions](https://www.pjsip.org/porting.htm)? Have you [read about previous efforts](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Apjsip.org+freertos&ia=web)? I get the feeling that your platform is rather too small for that library.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles. For our [WiPhone](https://hackaday.io/project/159811-esp32-wiphone) project we implemented our own embedded-friendly SIP library, that works even with 520 Kb SRAM alone. However, using WiPhone's 16 Mb Flash and 4 Mb PSRAM I think it might be even possible to port PJSIP.

Comment: Thanks for the insights